# Mercado Pago - transaction_amount attribute can't be null - c#

Tags: c#, api, mercadopago

Estoy programando con la API de MercadoPago en C# y al intentar hacer un pago de una cuota sola, me da siempre el error:

> 4002: transaction_amount attribute can't be null

sin embargo le estoy mandando el monto de la transacción en el objeto "pay".

Muchas Gracias.

```
  var request = new RestRequest("v1/payments", Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter("access_token", token.access_token);
        request.AddParameter("Public_key:", Config.GetPublicKey(_mode));

        var payer = new Customer()
        {
            first_name = "PEPE",
            last_name = "LUIS",
            email = "pepeLuis@email.com"
        };


        var pay = new Payment()
        {
            transaction_amount = 100,
            token = "03eb840972fb016800a7a316b46ae9c9",
            description = "Compra nº 1",
            installments = 1,
            payer = payer,
            payment_method_id = "visa",
            application_fee = 5.75
        };

        request.AddObject(pay);

        // execute the request
        var response = client.Execute(request);**
```

Comment: Hola AndreaFonr, bienvenid@! , aprovecho para invitarte a realizar el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y además revisa por favor [ask] para que en base a la información realices tu pregunta de acuerdo a el  [help] y sea bien recibida por la comunidad, además de obtener mejor respuesta!. Saludos!.

Comment: AndreaFonr de donde tomaste este ejemplo? veo que creas un objeto que tiene el atributo transaction_amount , no es la forma correcta de realizar la petición.

Comment: Porque no usas la libreria de Mercado pago: https://www.mercadopago.com.co/developers/en/tools/sdk/server/dotnet#basic-checkout

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, gracias por responder. Mira yo estaba trabajando con ese mismo código pero en vez de crear objetos le mandaba parámetros y me daba el mismo error.

request.AddParameter("access_token", token.access_token);
request.AddParameter("Public_key:", Config.GetPublicKey(_mode));
request.AddParameter("transaction_mount:", 100);
request.AddParameter("description:", "Compra nº 1");
request.AddParameter("installments:", 1);
request.AddParameter("payment_method_id:", "visa");
request.AddParameter("payer:", payer);

var response = client.Execute(request);